# Redshift DEFAULT GETDATE() working on INSERT but not COPY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a column  with a default constraint in my Redshift table so that the current timestamp will be populated for it.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    ...
    etl_date_time timestamp DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ...
);
```

This works as expected on INSERTS, but I still get null values when copying a json file from S3 that has no key for this column

```
COPY test_table FROM 's3://bucket/test_file.json' 
CREDENTIALS '...' FORMAT AS JSON 'auto';

// There shouldn't be any NULLs here, but there are
select count(*) from test_table where etl_date_time is null;
```

I have also tried putting a null value for the key in the source JSON, but that resulted in NULL values in the table as well.

```
{
    ...
    "etl_date_time": null,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the field is always `NULL`, consider omitting it from the files at S3 at all. `COPY` let's you specify the columns you intend to copy and will populate missing ones with their `DEFAULT` values.

So for the file `data.json`:

```
{"col1":"r1_val1", "col3":"r1_val2"}
{"col1":"r2_val1", "col3":"r2_val2"}
```

And the table definition:

```
create table _test (
    col1 varchar(20)
  , col2 timestamp default getdate()
  , col3 varchar(20)
);
```

### Specific column names

The `COPY` command with explicit column names

```
copy _test(col1,col3) from 's3://bucket/data.json' format as json 'auto'
```

Would yield the following result:

```
db=# select * from _test;
  col1   |        col2         |  col3
---------+---------------------+---------
 r1_val1 | 2016-07-27 18:27:08 | r1_val2
 r2_val1 | 2016-07-27 18:27:08 | r2_val2
(2 rows)
```

### Omitted column names

If the column names are omitted,

```
copy _test from 's3://bucket/data.json' format as json 'auto'
```

Would never use the `DEFAULT` but insert `NULL` instead:

```
db=# select * from _test;
  col1   |        col2         |  col3
---------+---------------------+---------
 r1_val1 |                     | r1_val2
 r2_val1 |                     | r2_val2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Right, what I'm reading is that with JSON the column mapping as you describe should happen automatically, based on the keys in the S3 file: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html#copy-column-list

Comment: Yes. The point is to omit the field `etl_date_time` from your JSON. As soon as it's present, its `DEFAULT` value apparently will not be used.

Comment: Understood... originally there was no etl_date_time key in the file and I got these results. I only tried adding the key with a null value afterwards

Comment: I have edited my original reply. I hope this clarifies what I wanted to say.

Comment: That worked - thanks for the specific JSON example. Missing keys seems like the perfect case for DEFAULT, so it is strange, though